# How can I compute the following complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $f(z)=Re(z)$ and $\gamma=\{|z|=1\}$ be the unit circle oriented counterclockwise. Compute $\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-1/2}~dz$

From the lecture we know that $f(z)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$ on $\gamma$.

My idea was to apply Cauchy's integral formula to compute $\int_\gamma \frac{\frac{z^2+1}{2z}}{z-1/2}~dz$.

But I'm a but confused how to define my $\Omega$ where $f$ is analytic. I don't think that I can apply Cauchy's integral formula directly on this integral but I don't see why. Could someone help me?

Comment: Yeah, you have two poles (at $0$ and $\frac12$), so you need to adapt. Either suitably deform your contour so that it's essentially two circles, one around each pole, or if you covered it already, use the residue theorem.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos but I mean one pole $\frac{1}{2}$ is not "important" since I could still alley Cauchy right? only the $0$ one causes problem?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos no we have never spoken about the residue theorem. Sorry I don't see what you mean by suitably deform your contour. You mean I need to deform $\gamma$?

Comment: They're both important. The integral formula is a formula which allows you to calculate integrals of functions with a single pole. This one has two poles, and that's the issue. Neither of the two poles is more or less important than the other. If either one of them wasn't there, you could apply Cauchy. But they're both there, so you can't apply it directly. That's why you should deform your contour so that you get "subcontours" which go around only one pole each, so that Cauchy works there.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos sorry but what do you mean by contour? I first of all don't understand this due to my bad English skills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Consider this picture. I marked the two poles at $0$ and $\frac12$. The outer circle is the contour $\gamma$. Consider the two closed contours given by the "upper half circle" and the "lower half circle". They do not enclose a pole and so the integral along these contours evaluate to $0$ according to Cauchy's theorem. But also, the integrals along those two contours are the same as the integral along $\gamma$ (counterclockwise) plus the integrals along the two smaller circles (clockwise), since the integrals along the straight lines cancel (one integral going to the left, one to the right). So if I call the smaller circles $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_{\frac12}$, we have
$$\oint_{\gamma} g(z)\mathrm dz-\oint_{\gamma_0}g(z)\mathrm dz-\oint_{\gamma_{\frac12}}g(z)\mathrm dz=0.$$
The negative signs are to account for the orientation of the contours, and $g$ is just the function you're integrating. Now this means that
$$\oint_{\gamma} g(z)\mathrm dz=\oint_{\gamma_0}g(z)\mathrm dz+\oint_{\gamma_{\frac12}}g(z)\mathrm dz.$$
And the two integrals on the right you can calculate using Cauchy's integral formula, since they only enclose a single pole.

Comment: ah wow nice way thank you I take a closer look and ask if I have more questions!

Comment: Is it important what the radius of the small circles is? I mean the should not intersect but otherwise I can take a radius of my desire?

Comment: or how did you define $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_{1/2}$

Comment: The radius doesn't matter. Though sometimes Cauchy's theorem is formulated for star shaped domains only. Then you'd need to make additional cuts and choose the radii small enough so that you get star shaped domains.

Comment: perfect thanks. Another small question what did you mean by the upper half circle? I mean do we take the upper half plus the line between plus the two upper half of the small circles?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by half circle.

Comment: perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that$$\frac{f(z)}{z-1/2}=\frac12-\frac1z+\frac{5/4}{z-1/2}.$$Therefore\begin{align}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-1/2}\,\mathrm dz&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac12\,\mathrm dz-\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1z\,\mathrm dz+\frac54\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1{z-1/2}\,\mathrm dz\\&=0-2\pi i+\frac542\pi i\\&=\frac{\pi i}2.\end{align}

Comment: have you now used the method of  deform the contour as we discussed above? Or how do you get to your new representation of $\frac{f(z)}{z-1/2}$

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Ah okey could you maybe explain me what he meant by deform the contour? Because I can't imagine what this is

Comment: I can't help you there. I also have no idea. My contour is the one from your problem, without any deformation.

Comment: Ah okey thank you